# Multicommodity shortest path problem on a directed acyclic graph

Tags: shortest-path, weighted-graphs

I have n commodities with each a unique source and sink node. Each source-sink pair is connected in some manner on a directed acyclic graph. All arc weights are non-negative. The goal is to find the shortest paths to transport the commodities between their respective source-sink pairs.

Is there any algorithm that can solve this kind of problem rapidly, possibly using topological sorting first? How is this affected if there is unlimited/limited capacity on the arcs?

Many thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the all-pairs shortest path problem, which can be solved with [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

Comment: Do any capacity restrictions or any other interactions between the commodities exist? If not what you can e.g. use Dijkstra on each pair independently.